How can I group an array of tuplets by common elements?
I have a series of segments defined as an array of two tuplets (two vertices).  Each segment can share a vertex with another segment and it is possible that a combination of segments will form one or more closed loops.
In order to find the closed loops my current approach would be to find which lines are connected (share a vertex) and group them before ordering each group clockwise.
Let's take the following example (written in Python)
lines = {
    "A": [(0, 0), (0, 1)],  # A,B -- B,C
    "B": [(0, 1), (1, 1)],  # |       |
    "C": [(1, 1), (1, 0)],  # |       |
    "D": [(1, 0), (0, 0)],  # A,D -- C,D
    
    "E": [(4, 4), (4, 5)],  # E,F - F,G
    "F": [(4, 5), (5, 5)],  # |   /
    "G": [(5, 5), (4, 4)],  # E,G
}

answer = ["ABCD", "EFG"]

What would be the best way to group the entries (using the standard Python library) that share a vertex (tuplet value)?  The order in which the lines are found in the dictionary is not guaranteed but ordered clockwise here to make it easier to read.
I have tried a simple cycle approach (graph theory) to this problem but the cycles returned included many more than I wanted using the vertices in the example above so I have revisited my approach to the problem which resulted in me asking this question.

What should the output be if the D entry weren't in the input?

In terms of grouping then the answer would be ["ABC", "EFG"].  The fact that it does not form a closed loop is fine as that topic is only the background to this question and not the question itself.

Since you asked for a solution that only involves the standard library, here's one.

Create an adjacency list, where each key is a vertex and the list of values is a list of the edges for that vertex

from collections import defaultdict

adjacency_list = defaultdict(list)
for key, (v1, v2) in lines.items():
    adjacency_list[v1].append((v2, key))
    adjacency_list[v2].append((v1, key))

print(adjacency_list) # {(0, 0): [((0, 1), 'A'), ((1, 0), 'D')], ...}


Traverse the graph using depth-first search

def depth_first_search(node, visited, adjacency_list, path):
    """Traverse the graph to find connected components"""
    stack = [(node, None)]
    while stack:
        v, parent = stack.pop()
        if v in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(v)
        path.append(v)
        for neighbor, line in adjacency_list[v]:
            if neighbor not in visited:
                stack.append((neighbor, v))
    return path

visited = set()

filtered_list = filter(lambda node: node not in visited, adjacency_list)
components = map(lambda node: depth_first_search(node, visited, adjacency_list, []), filtered_list)


Find the loops from the components

def find_loops(component, adjacency_list):
    if not component:
        return ""
    
    # Find the loop by following the path
    loop = []
    visited_edges = set()
    current_node = component[0]
    
    while True:
        for neighbor, line in adjacency_list[current_node]:
            if current_node < neighbor:
              edge = (current_node, neighbor)
            else:
              edge = (neighbor, current_node)
            if edge not in visited_edges:
                visited_edges.add(edge)
                loop.append(line)
                current_node = neighbor
                break
        else:
            break
    
    return "".join(sorted(loop))

answer = [find_loops(component, adjacency_list) for component in components]

print(answer) # ['ABCD', 'EFG']

If the code is not clear enough, I can explain it some more.

I'm seeing TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable when calling find_loops

I don't get that error, but components = list(components) should fix it

That gives me TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' instead.

I can do the following instead to work around the issue
for c in components:     answer = find_loops(c, adjacency_list)     print(answer)

This can be approached with a graph library such as networkx, considering each pair of coordinate as an edge.
You could then use connected components or simple_cycles depending on the exact expected logic:
import networkx as nx
from itertools import pairwise

G = nx.from_edgelist(lines.values(), create_using=nx.DiGraph)

names = {tuple(v):k for k,v in lines.items()}
# {((0, 0), (0, 1)): 'A',
#  ((0, 1), (1, 1)): 'B',
#  ((1, 1), (1, 0)): 'C',
#  ((1, 0), (0, 0)): 'D',
#  ((4, 4), (4, 5)): 'E',
#  ((4, 5), (5, 5)): 'F',
#  ((5, 5), (4, 4)): 'G'}

# connected components
# the order of the edges is not guaranteed
cc = [[names[e] for e in G.subgraph(c).edges() if e in names]
      for c in nx.weakly_connected_components(G)]
# [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]

# cycles
# the order of the edges will be correct
cy = [[names[(c[-1], c[0])]]+[names[e] for e in pairwise(c)]
      for c in nx.simple_cycles(G)]
# [['G', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]

Graph:

